# my project works with live server extension only

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I have a live server extension in my VC and it works well, the problem is when I try to open my page without using the extension it shows up the page without any CSS colors or images or anything, I want to see my project with all CSS codes I wrote without using live server, thank you

Comment: This might be a case of [Why does my file load correctly through Live Server, but not through my browsers' support for the file:// protocol?](/q/75637309/11107541), but it's impossible to know right now without a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried copying the full path of the file then entering it in the browser?
If that still doesn't work, try refresh the page when updating your html/css/js file.

Comment: the path is normal, my problem is the page looks like I didn't use any CSS codes unless I opened the page using live server, it works well with the live server but otherwise, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your code will help us more to Debug it.
Instead, I suggest you,

- Just recheck your internet connection if you're using any CDN or any API like Bootstrap, Tailwind CSS.
- Check your links if referred to any external CSS or js.

Comment: This should be a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment#:~:text=What%20are%20comments%3F,they%27re%20gone%20for%20good.) not an answer

Comment: there is no problem with my connection my friend, the only problem I have is when I try to open my project by clicking on the index file in my project folder, it looks like I didn't write any CSS codes, but it works well when I open it using live server in visual studio.

Comment: Then Sharing your code is the only option.

Comment: here is the code, it works well in codepen but it doesn't look like this in the broweser
https://codepen.io/am01504/pen/NWvBrQj

Comment: Place your both css files reference in the last, Above </head> tag.